# Can a TypeProvider add a Resource to the generated assembly?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Is it possible for a generative type provider, when using the ProvidedTypes API, to add resources in addition to types to the assembly?

I'd like to build in specific resources generated along with the concrete types built by my provider.  If this is possible, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: +1 I've been wondering about this myself recently.

Comment: @JackP. It looks like its not directly possible - though if you write the plumbing for the type provider yourself, resources from the assembly you generate seem to be mixed in.  Trying some more detailed experiments now to verify, though I think it works in that case.  Don't see how to do it with the ProvidedTypes API/base classes in the samples, though.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be in the same assembly? You can only generate types, you have no control of the assembly that F# generates, but if it doesn't need to be in the same assembly, maybe you can generate an assembly with resources manually and then use a generated type provider to reference that. But it will probably be a long shot

Comment: That would basically force it to reference another assembly, though, right?  Not sure how the original assembly would have access to those types in that case.

Comment: I think in generated type providers you always reference another assembly, but I'm not sure as I've only developed erased type providers. https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series/wiki/INotifyPropertyChanged-Type-Provider and https://github.com/colinbull/JavaTypeProvider use generated types, take a look at them for examples

Comment: Yes - with a generated type provider, it creates another assembly and static links it in.  The ProvidedTypes APIs/examples always use that API to build that assembly using F# quotations, which is really clean and nice (and it provides the plumbing to specify the types for intellisense, etc).  Just not sure if there's a way to do this without redoing all of that plumbing work myself - but suspect its not possible :(